# During the construction of the decision tree . Why will the attribute with the highest information gain will be used as the root node?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

Like at this picture from edureka it has been seen that the outlook attribute has the highest information gain . From what I understand higher information gain means that the data will tend to be homogeneous and have more purity but still I can't proof why the attribute with highest information gain will be used as the root node .
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology - please see the intro and NOTE in the `machine-learning` [tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/machine-learning/info).

Answer (score 1):

It is a **decision** tree. So, we need to decide in each node that an entry data goes down which branch of the tree. Hence, the attribute with the highest information gain can help us to divide entries into a more meaningful division because it contains more information than other attributes.